# Constructor not working, compile error

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, oop

I was looking at a game engine code and I tried to reproduce myself but I got a compile error.

Main.as

```
package {
  import flash.display.Sprite;

  public class Main extends Sprite
  {
    public function Main():void
    {
       var firstDoes:AB1 = new AB1();
       firstDoes.secondDoes._AB2();             
    }
  }
}
```

AB1.as

```
package {
  import flash.display.Sprite;

  public class AB1 extends Sprite
  {
    var secondDoes:AB2 = new AB2();

    public function _AB1():void
    {                   
    }
  }
}
```

AB2.as

```
package {
  import flash.display.Sprite;

  public class AB2 extends Sprite
  {
    public function _AB2():void
    {
        this.graphics.beginFill(0x33FF22);
        this.graphics.drawCircle(50, 50, 20);
        this.graphics.endFill();
        this.addChild(this);
    }
  }
}
```

Why isn't it working ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please show us the error message that is shown and tell use which line is giving the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried running this code.  I don't get a compile error, but I DO get a runtime error.  You can't add yourself as a child:

```
this.addChild(this); // <-------- BOOM!
```

Comment: Yeah, that was to be expected... he is adding the child to itself while it is still in the constructor, meaning he adds something when it's not created yet ^^

Comment: He's also trying to add himself to himself, which isn't possible.

Comment: @JNDPNT I was more pointing out that `this` was adding `this` which doesn't make sense.  Note that he is not actually doing this in a constructor... he is doing it in a function that looks like a constructor bit it isn't actually one :)

Comment: Lol, I missed that part. Thanks for updating me.

Comment: I don't see any import statements either

Answer (score 3):

Is it intentional that you have an underscore in your AB1 and AB2 constructor? If not, I would suggest renaming "_AB1" to "AB1", and "_AB2" to "AB2".

Answer (score 1):

try deleting `this.addChild(this);` from AB2, changing `var secondDoes:AB2 = new AB2();` to `public var secondDoes:AB2 = new AB2();` and adding `addChild(secondDoes);` to AB1 constructor

Answer (score 0):

`Class` name and `constructor` name should be the same.

`var secondDoes:AB2;` Make this as `public`.

`graphics` is the property of `DisplayObject`, so you should use
   `MovieClip` or `Sprite` or `Shape` to create your circle.

Main class :

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class Main extends Sprite    {
        public function Main():void     {
            var firstDoes:AB1 = new AB1();
            addChild(firstDoes);
        }
    }
}
```

AB1 class :

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class AB1 extends Sprite {
        public var secondDoes:AB2;
        public function AB1():void{
            secondDoes = new AB2();
            addChild(secondDoes);
        }
    }
}
```

AB2 class :

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    public class AB2 extends Sprite {
        public var my_mc:Sprite = new Sprite();
        public function AB2():void      {
            my_mc = new Sprite();
            my_mc.graphics.beginFill(0x33FF22);
            my_mc.graphics.drawCircle(50, 50, 20);
            my_mc.graphics.endFill();
            addChild(my_mc);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that the issue is with

```
public function Main():void
```

A constructor can't have a return type. You should rather use

```
public function Main()
```